# how to show image in asp.net website using c#

Tags: asp.net

At first when i debugged my asp.net website .aspx file,it was shown in browser but when I viewed in chrome it showed error:

XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: file:///D:/bind/Default.aspx
Line Number 1, Column 2:<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
-^

Comment: Can you give us the code where you are trying to display your image? Sounds like you have the directory path setup incorrectly. Edit: I didn't read it close enough. Look at what Joe Enos said.

Comment: Stop having other people do your homework would be a good start to solving your problem(s).

Answer (score 4):

You can't run `aspx` pages through the `file:///` protocol. You need to run using HTTP (or HTTPS) through IIS (or something similar, like IIS Express or Cassini in Visual Studio).

When you use `file:///`, it will only work with static HTML pages.

Comment: Is there any connection between asp.net server and internet

Comment: @user2653867 You'd want to load the page from VS to test it. VS has a development server.

Comment: I debugged a website in my laptop using vs and it loaded in the browser but the same file when I tried to debug in my pc,the browser keeps on loading.I couldn't find out the problem